# Onidle task starting after specific date

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a batch file that will (among other things) create task for Windows Task Scheduler that should be executed every time computer goes idle for some time but should start executing that task only after the specific date.
When I tried to write it like that

```
schtasks /create /TN "Connection Configuration" /SC onidle /i 5 /sd 12/13/2018 /tr "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\client.bat"
```

I get the error message telling that /SD parameter can't be used with onidle.
Is there any other way to do that on Windows 10 Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `/create` parameter.

This works for me:

```
schtasks /create /tn test123 /sc onidle /i 1 /sd 09/12/2018 /tr "cmd /c mkdir test123"
```

`/sd` can be used but `/st` cannot.

If this is not enough, export the task as XML, modify it, and then import with

```
schtasks /create /xml c:\path\to\file.xml /tn INSERT_TASKNAME_HERE
```

Comment: I didn't forget /create my full code looks like that `schtasks /create /TN "Connection Configuration" /SC onidle /i 5 /sd 12/13/2018 /tr "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\client.bat"` and I get error message precisely about /SD At the moment I'm thinking that the best workaround would be creating task that at certain will create another task that will be executed onidle but I'm still open for advices. I can't copy the error message because I use non-english Windows 10 Pro. Generally it just says /RI /DU /ST /SD /ET /ED /K can't be used with onstart, onlogon, onidle and onevent.

Comment: Why did you post a different command line then? Please edit your question to include this command line and your OS version. Your command works on my test system but I don't have windows-10 one handy to test at the moment. Try my suggestion on exporting/importing the task as XML please. A task creating another task may actually work too. try creating a batch file containing something like `echo PASSWORD | schtasks /create............` and then scheduling that file to run at specific date. This will expose the password in cleartext though - so may be bad for security.

Comment: I posted the shortest string that gave that exact error message. Edited the main post. What version of Windows did you use to run that code?